# Java, Pattern matching and sorting from a file

Tags: java, error-handling, pattern-matching, bufferedreader, filereader

I'm attempting to read through a given text file and sort through it using pattern matching based on address given, When reading through the file though im getting a weird NumberFormatException error on the 45 5th ave lines and im not understanding what this error means and why its occuring from this line but not from another like 22 broadway which prints out just fine. Also should i be using scanner for this instead or is bufferedreader okay to be using for this project and how could nonpattern matching lines be stored to be outputted later in the output as addresses that didnt match?

**TEXT FILE**

```
123-ABC-4567, 15 W. 15th St., 50.1
456-BGT-9876,22 Broadway,24
QAZ-456-QWER, 100 East 20th Street,50
Q2Z-457-QWER, 200 East 20th Street, 49
6578-FGH-9845 ,,45 5th Ave, 12.2,
678-FGH-9846 ,45 5th Ave, 12.2

123-ABC-9999, 46 Foo Bar, 220.0
347-poy-3465, 101 B'way,24
```

**CODE SO FAR**

```
package csi311;

// Import some standard Java libraries.
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;


public class HelloCsi311 {

   /**
    * Class construtor.
    */
   public HelloCsi311() {
   }


/**
 * @param filename the name of a file to read in 
 * @throws Exception on anything bad happening 
 */
public void run(String filename) throws Exception {
 System.out.println("Hello world");
 if (filename != null) {
  readFile(filename); 
 }
}


/**
 * @param filename the name of a file to read in 
 * @throws Exception on anything bad happening 
 */
private void readFile(String filename) throws Exception {
 System.out.println("Dumping file " + filename); 
 // Open the file and connect it to a buffered reader.
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));  
 String line = null;  
 String pattern = "^\\d\\d\\d-[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]-\\d\\d\\d\\d";
 String address = "\\d{1,3}\\s\\[A-Za-z]{2,20}";
 // Get lines from the file one at a time until there are no more.
 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   String[] result = line.split(",");
   for(String str : result)
   {
     String pkgId = result[0].trim().toUpperCase();
     String pkgAddr = result[1];
     Float f = Float.valueOf(result[2]);
     if (!pkgId.matches(pattern)) {

     }
     else


       System.out.println(str);
     }
 }






 // Close the buffer and the underlying file.
 br.close();
}



   /**
    * @param args filename
    */
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Make an instance of the class.
    HelloCsi311 theApp = new HelloCsi311();
    String filename = null; 
    // If a command line argument was given, use it as the filename.
    if (args.length > 0) {
     filename = args[0]; 
    }
    try { 
     // Run the run(), passing in the filename, null if not specified.
     theApp.run(filename);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
     // If anything bad happens, report it.
     System.out.println("Something bad happened!");
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
```

}

**ERROR Im Recieving**

```
  java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "45 5th Ave"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Float.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at csi311.HelloCsi311.readFile(HelloCsi311.java:52)
    at csi311.HelloCsi311.run(HelloCsi311.java:29)
    at csi311.HelloCsi311.main(HelloCsi311.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:267)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.symbol.JavaClass$JavaMethod.evaluate(JavaClass.java:362)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.ExpressionEvaluator.handleMethodCall(ExpressionEvaluator.java:92)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.ExpressionEvaluator.visit(ExpressionEvaluator.java:84)
    at koala.dynamicjava.tree.StaticMethodCall.acceptVisitor(StaticMethodCall.java:121)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.ExpressionEvaluator.value(ExpressionEvaluator.java:38)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.ExpressionEvaluator.value(ExpressionEvaluator.java:37)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.StatementEvaluator.visit(StatementEvaluator.java:106)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.StatementEvaluator.visit(StatementEvaluator.java:29)
    at koala.dynamicjava.tree.ExpressionStatement.acceptVisitor(ExpressionStatement.java:101)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.StatementEvaluator.evaluateSequence(StatementEvaluator.java:66)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.Interpreter.evaluate(Interpreter.java:77)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:47)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.repl.newjvm.InterpreterJVM.interpret(InterpreterJVM.java:249)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.repl.newjvm.InterpreterJVM.interpret(InterpreterJVM.java:222)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
```

Comment: You are splitting on a comma, one the good rows the value you are wanting to parse is in the second column but the bad rows do not seems to be aligned the same GIGO?

Comment: this row is in incorrect format `6578-FGH-9845 ,,45 5th Ave, 12.2,`

Comment: Thank you guys for the advice! While adjusting the text document fixes that issue, this incorrect format was given to me although so i was wondering if there was a way to work around it and it still be able to function properly or do you believe that this given text document is the only problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`6578-FGH-9845 ,,45 5th Ave, 12.2,` A crucial part of your code is splitting by `,` and you accidentally have 2 commas in one place. This causes it to skip a section and try to format it as a number; making it throw the exception. The corrected line would look like `6578-FGH-9845, 45 5th Ave, 12.2`

Comment: It does not look like anything is skipped, the value is the third column is expected to be a `Float`

Comment: The double comma `,,` causes a section to be skipped

Comment: Thank you for the help! While this errorfull text was given to me i believe that may have solved this problem for the most part but now im getting an `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1` after the lines `678-FGH-9846 ,45 5th Ave, 12.2` are read and dont seem to be able to proceed past the entirely blank space line even though i should have trimmed out that line with the `String pkgId = result[0].trim().toUpperCase();` when i get to that line

Comment: the majority of the error is as follows `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at csi311.HelloCsi311.readFile(HelloCsi311.java:51)
 at csi311.HelloCsi311.run(HelloCsi311.java:29)
 at csi311.HelloCsi311.main(HelloCsi311.java:87)`

Comment: `trim()` does not filter it out, you need to add an if statement check at the top of your `while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)`. Add `if (line.trim().isEmpty()) continue;` at the top of your while.

Comment: Thank you so much! Feel kind of silly now as that was much simpler then i thought it was, although now for some reason the white spaces after the split commas dont seem to be being ignored and are being printed but `String pkgId = result[0].trim().toUpperCase();
         String pkgAddr = result[1].trim();` should be trimming them off. Is the way im going about this correct?